# segmentation fault while printing with cout

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am about to go nuts over this segmentation fault. I am writing a simple 2 pass assembler. Stripping of the intermediate file to get op-codes, symbol table entries etc. is working fine.  I am printing the machine code buffer to the console for now, but something is causing segmentation fault.

```
#include"./assembler.h"
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
ifstream inf("pooltab");
int pooltab[10],pooltab_ptr=0;

while(true)
{
    int x;
    inf>>x;
    if(inf.eof()) break;
    pooltab[pooltab_ptr++] = x;
}
for(int i=0;i<pooltab_ptr;i++)
    cout<<pooltab[i]<<endl;
pooltab_ptr = 0;
inf.close();

inf.open("intermediate.asm");
//  ofstream outf("machine_code");  
    sym_tab symtab;
literal_tab littab;

symtab.create_tab();
littab.create_tab();

char buf[50],*token,*m_code_buf,ch;
int loc_cntr=0,id,ltrl,a,b;

while(true)
{
    inf.getline(buf,50);
    if(inf.eof()) break;
    token = strtok(buf,"(), ");
    if(token != NULL)
    {
        if(token[0] == 'A' && token[1] == 'D')
        {
            token = strtok(NULL,",)");
            if(token == NULL)
            {
                cerr<<"null token error";
                return -1;
            }
            id = atoi(token);
            if(id == 1 || id == 2)
            {
                token = strtok(NULL,",() C");
                                    if(token == NULL)
                {
                    cerr<<"null token error";
                    return -1;
                } 
                loc_cntr = atoi(token);
            }
        }

        if(token[0] == 'I' && token[1] == 'S')
        {
            token = strtok(NULL,",)");
            if(token == NULL) 
            {
                cerr<<"null token error";
                return -1;
            }
            id = atoi(token);
            if(id == 10 || id == 11)
            {
                token = strtok(NULL,"S,() ");
                if(token == NULL)
                { 
                    cerr<<"null token error";
                    return -1;
                }
                a = atoi(token);
                a = symtab.get_addr(a);
                sprintf(m_code_buf,"%03d) + %02d 0 %03d\n",loc_cntr,id,a);  
                cout<<m_code_buf;
            }
            else if(id == 1)
            {
                sprintf(m_code_buf,"%03d) + %02d 0 000\n",loc_cntr,id);
                printf("%s",m_code_buf);
            }
            else if(id > 1 || id < 10)
            {
                token = strtok(NULL,"() ");
                if(token == NULL)
                { 
                    cerr<<"null token error"; 
                    return -1;
                }
                a = token[0] - 48;
                token = strtok(NULL," (,");
                if(token == NULL)
                {
                    cerr<<"null token error"; 
                    return -1;
                }
                ch = token[0];
                printf("%d %d %c \n",id,a,ch);
            }

            loc_cntr++;
        }
    }
}
inf.close();
//  outf.close();

return 0;
}
```

This is the way I am checking for imperative statements `(IS,1) (1) (S,1)` in the intermediate code file. The error is at the `sprintf`. Now the fault just seems to jump from one place to the other as I make changes to the code.
Ex. at one point I was using `cout` instead of `printf`. Then the `sprintf` was just fine but the cout generated the fault. then I change the way pooltab is generated and now `sprintf` is the troublemaker.

Comment: You are probably causing undefined behaviour somewhere. Show us the full function (and the definition of token).

Comment: The actual code is too big and yet not complete but ok.

Comment: char m_code_buf[256];A simple change did it. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: I am still kinda irked over this, is it something about the pointers that i don't know but all of you do? because the same sprintf statement had been working earlier.

Comment: I provided an answer that explains it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that `m_code_buf` is either not initialized or too small.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(token == NULL) cerr<<"null token error";
a = atoi(token);
```

If `token` is `NULL`, you just passed `NULL` to `atoi`...

Comment: Ok, now all error checks are in place but no luck.In ID = 1 of IS sprintf is still creating problems.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays and pointers are not the same.

Currently, you've defined `m_code_buf` as a pointer to `char`:

```
char *m_code_buf;
```

That is *just* a pointer. It doesn't point anywhere. There are no `char` objects that it's pointing at. You can't start treating it like it's actually pointing at any valid `char` objects. Just because the type tells you it's going to point a `char`, doesn't meant that it does automatically.

When you change it to:

```
char m_code_buf[256];
```

This gives you an array of `char`. It literally allocates 256 `char` sized objects in memory for you to use. It is then fine to pass this to `sprintf`.

But `m_code_buf` here is not a pointer. However, the name of an array is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element in many contexts. That's why you can start treating the name of an array as though it were a pointer, even though it *isn't*.

Answer (score 0):

It may just mean that you wanna write more than your buffer can take. It makes you write on someone's else memory (segfault).